# Mule - Anypoint Studio - save files from multipart/form-data request

Tags: file, mule, esb, anypoint-studio

I'm using Mule file connector to save files to directory sent from `multipart/form-data` http request, i need to only save files with `.jpg, .pdf` extensions, how can i filter that?
I see file name filtering for `<file:inbound-endpoint` but not for `<file:outbound-endpoint`,
appreciate any pointers

```
<file:outbound-endpoint path="." outputPattern="\archive\#[variable:Filename]" connector-ref="Documents" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Save document"/>

<file:connector name="Documents" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File" writeToDirectory="temp"  recursive="true">
    </file:connector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Outbound will always write data, use choice route before outbound to skip it for unrequired file types.